# gitlab won't start after the mysqld pid file error, and innodb file size issues

Tags: mysql, gitlab

My gitlab installation just won't start, since the last restart.

the mysqld.pid file is not there as well.

```
131111 18:20:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log'.
131111 18:20:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld.bin daemon with databases from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
131111 18:20:58 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
```

I looked into the mysqld.log

```
tail -f mysql/data/mysqld.log 
131111 18:30:24 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
131111 18:30:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131111 18:30:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131111 18:30:24  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ib_logfile0
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
131111 18:30:24 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
```

does that mean, mysqld use doesn't have access rights to /opt/bitnami/mysql/data

I also see this error now

```
tail -f mysql/data/mysqld.log 
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile1 is of different size 0 327680 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
131111 18:34:57 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
131111 18:34:57 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
131111 18:34:57 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
131111 18:34:57 [ERROR] Aborting

131111 18:34:57 [Note] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin: Shutdown complete

131111 18:34:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself

1. deleted all the ib_logfiles 0 and 1
2. made entry for the logfile size in my.cnf as 
   innodb_log_file_size=125M

and restarted the server with sh ctlscript.sh start and it started like a charm.